# parentNode.getElementById() is not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I encountered a problem while practicing html. When I used `parentNode` in JavaScript, I thought it is not hard to treat.

But to get some element under `parentNode` using `getElementById` or another function is not working as my thinking.

```
var this_question = selectObj.parentNode.parentNode;
    alert(this_question); //it is working perfectly
    alert(this_question.getElementById('question'))
```

It's not working. I can't understand...

```
<script>
function addQuestion(selectObj) {
    var this_question = selectObj.parentNode.parentNode;
    alert(this_question); //it is working perfectly
    alert(this_question.getElementById('question')) //It's not working. I can't understand..
}
</script>

<ol id="question_list">
    <li>
        <textarea class="question" name="question" id="question"></textarea>
        <select name="question_type" id="question_type" onChange="javascript:selectEvent(this)">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option value="text" >단답형</option>
            <option value="paragraph" >서술형</option>
            <option value="multiple_choice">다지선</option>
            <option value="checkbox">다중선택</option>
            <option value="scale">scale</option>
        </select>   

        <div id='answer_div'><p>부가설명:<input name='top_label' id='top_label' type='paragraph' /></p> <p>답변:<input name='answer_text' id='answer_text' type='text' /></p></div>

        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Add Question" onclick="javascript:addQuestion(this)"/>
            <input type="button" value="Done" onclick="javascript:finish()"/>
         </p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Which element are you trying to get a reference to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two elements with the same `id` attribute but `id` attributes must be unique:

1. `<ol id="question">`
2. `<textarea class="question" name="question" id="question"></textarea>`

When you duplicate `id` attributes strange things happen. If you change the `<textarea>` to have `id="question_text"`, for example, things start working better:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/67DZr/

From the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2):

> **id = name [CS]**
>   This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

and from the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute):

> The `id` attribute specifies its element's **unique identifier (ID)**. The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I edited id following your answer. But It's not working yet.
I tested this using getElementsByName also...

I tested this code on google Chrome and safari.

Comment: @sandfox: What do you mean "not working"? Which browser? Did you try the http://jsfiddle.net/ link in my question?

Comment: Oh I edited my comment again. Sorry :)
Chrome and Safari isn't working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/67DZr/ works for me in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera. Did you update the `id` in both the HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/67DZr is working for me also. But this code is not working yet on chrome through my server. :(... I'll try again.

Comment: And pay attention to Dr.Molle's advice, using `getElementById` on anything other than `document` is odd (but Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera are okay with it but the results aren't necessarily what you'd expect).

Comment: OK thank you. How about this?
I tried using getElementsByName.
 http://jsfiddle.net/67DZr/5/

Comment: Anyway thank you. It is working when I use getElementsByTagName instead of another. I solved my problem :)

Comment: That's only available on `document` and it returns a list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName

Comment: OK. I didn't know that function can be used only on document. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

getElementById() is a method of documents, not available in elements.

You may use:

```
this_question.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]
```

getElementsByTagName() is available in elements.

Comment: thank you :). it's perfect. but how about using getElementsByName()?
I can't understand why it's not working like TagName.

Comment: getElementsByName also isn't available in elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
baseElement.querySelector('#' + id)
```

It returns:

> The first descendant element of baseElement which matches the specified group of selectors.

---

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector